# Reputation decreased suddenly due to some users' serial upvotes by Moderator.!

Tags: discussion, bug

I feel very surprised by this and its also seems to be weird to ask such a silly question here but I had no option other than this and hence doing the same.

My reputation points were suddenly decreased by almost 1.5 K by one moderator https://stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9. The reason he/she did this was that some SO user is continuously accepting my answers as well as up voting them.

But when I asked him/her that, please let me know who is that user and also re-check about why this happened and requested to revert this back if there is some system glitch. I haven't received any response yet and hence asking this question here to know that, how come a system all of a sudden come to identify that points were earned by some offense ? Why system is not checking this after a short interval or so ? OR this is moderator based application where he/she will pickup random user account and revert some points back saying that they were unofficially earned.

Please help.! Appreciate your time and support in advance.!

Comment: There is no system glitch here; the votes should never have been given in the first place. All the moderator did was rectify what amounts to voting fraud.

Comment: You did read the link explaining why? http://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed

Comment: Also your request for who the voter was will not be answered as voting is anonymous.

Answer (score 7):

Comparing the amount of reversed votes with your posts, it looks like the user has upvoted almost all of your posts. That is clearly a misuse of the voting system, and such cases will be reversed if they draw the attention of the moderators.

In your case this was not any automatic mechanism that removed those votes, but an SE employee manually investigating the case. You could contact SE using the "contact us" link at the bottom, but I doubt that would achieve anything. SE generally doesn't remove votes unless they are sure that those votes were not legitimate.

Comment: I hope that upvoting a large proportion of a user's posts is not, in itself, misuse of the system. There is a particular user who is both a good writer and knows a lot about the subject of one of my favorite tags. I upvote a lot of his answers because they are extremely good answers on a subject where I can recognize a good answer.

Comment: It isn't @PatriciaShanahan. Not if you organically stumble upon their contribution and evaluate them as you see fit.

Comment: The key number here is 1520 from a single user...

Comment: @vba4all It was actually 2 events, which means it's from two different users not just one.

Comment: @animuson Oh Ok still...